# Helper script or dockerfile commands in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I have a question about best practices. Which method is recommended.

1. Having a helper script `install-plugins.sh` that installs all that is required during build time. Or...
2. Having the installations occur in the dockerfile by using `RUN` commands.

I know the 1st one enhances the readability of the dockerfile. How are these 2 comparable? And which is the better one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `entrypoint` for this purpose. It will run on each execution of container.
2. `RUN` runs only on build time when image creating.

For example, first solution could be implemented when you need to update packages on each container execution but in this case starting it could be more slowly. Also helper could update some Environment settings on each execution.

Comment: You should generally install plugins and other packages at build time, not at startup time.  If you try to do it at startup time, there's a real potential for failure if the remote package server is down, your local network is spotty, ... and it is repeating work you should just be doing once and saving.

Comment: In context of Python developing on local host we use `pip install` within entrypoint script to obtain fresh packages anytime they needed (without rebuild) by changing env variable PIP_UPGRADE_RUNTIME to 1.